# BankAccount in python , got wrong result

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to code these lines in python.

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, initial_balance):
        """Creates an account with the given balance."""
        …
    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Deposits the amount into the account."""
        …
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """
        Withdraws the amount from the account.  Each withdrawal resulting in a
        negative balance also deducts a penalty fee of 5 dollars from the balance.
        """
        …
    def get_balance(self):
        """Returns the current balance in the account."""
        …
    def get_fees(self):
        """Returns the total fees ever deducted from the account."""
    …
```

"The deposit and withdraw methods each change the account balance. The withdraw method also deducts a fee of 5 dollars from the balance if the withdrawal (before any fees) results in a negative balance. Since we also have the method get_fees, you will need to have a variable to keep track of the fees paid.

Here's one possible test of the class. It should print the values 10 and 5, respectively, since the withdrawal incurs a fee of 5 dollars. 
"

but i have got a wrong results , the first is OK but the second result is wrong 
any advise please
this is my code

```
## python BankAccount program#################

fees = 0
class BankAccount:
        def __init__(self, init_bal):

        """Creates an account with the given balance."""
        self.init_bal = init_bal
        self.account = init_bal 
        self.fees = fees


    def deposit(self, amount):

        """Deposits the amount into the account."""
        self.amount = amount
        self.account += amount


    def withdraw(self, amount):

        """
        Withdraws the amount from the account.  Each withdrawal resulting in a
        negative balance also deducts a penalty fee of 5 dollars from the balance.
        """

        self.account -= amount
        if self.account < 0:
            self.account -= 5

        self.fees += 5




    def get_balance(self):

        """Returns the current balance in the account."""
        return self.account

    def get_fees(self):

        """Returns the total fees ever deducted from the account."""

        return self.fees


###### First account ###########################    
my_account_1 = BankAccount(10)
my_account_1.withdraw(15)
my_account_1.deposit(20)
my_account_1.withdraw(25)
print my_account_1.get_balance(), my_account_1.get_fees()
####### second account########################
my_account = BankAccount(10)
my_account.withdraw(5)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(5)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(20)
my_account.withdraw(5) 
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.deposit(20)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(30)
my_account.withdraw(10)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(50) 
my_account.deposit(30)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(5) 
my_account.deposit(20)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.deposit(30)
my_account.withdraw(25) 
my_account.withdraw(5)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(10) 
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.deposit(30)
my_account.withdraw(25) 
my_account.withdraw(10)
my_account.deposit(20)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(5) 
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(5) 
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(5) 
print my_account.get_balance(), my_account.get_fees()

the results are : -20 10 (first result)
                  -60 115 (second result)
```

Comment: _"but i have got a wrong results"_. What are the correct results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def withdraw(self, amount):

    """
    Withdraws the amount from the account.  Each withdrawal resulting in a
    negative balance also deducts a penalty fee of 5 dollars from the balance.
    """

    self.account -= amount
    if self.account < 0:
        self.account -= 5

    self.fees += 5
```

Here, you are adding 5 to fees regardless of whether the account is being penalized or not. Put the last line inside the `if` block.

```
    if self.account < 0:
        self.account -= 5
        self.fees += 5
```

Comment: so much thanks Kevin , yes i missed that , now the program run correctly .